# Captcha refresh (mewebstudio)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4, captcha

**Purpose :** to refresh the captcha image.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/get_captcha/{config?}', function (\Mews\Captcha\Captcha $captcha, $config = 'default') {
    return $captcha->src($config);
});
```

**captcha image (mypage.blade.php):**

```
<img src="{{ Captcha::img() }}" alt="captcha" class="captcha-img" data-refresh-config="default">
```

**js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.captcha-img').on('click', function () {
        var captcha = $(this);
        var config = captcha.data('refresh-config');
        //console.log(config);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/get_captcha/' + config,
        }).done(function (response) {
            captcha.prop('src', response);
        });
    });
});
```

**Issue :**  js ajax error on my console : `http://localhost/get_captcha/default 404` error.

reference : https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha/issues/54#issuecomment-141483501

**Additional information :** I'm using captcha for Laravel 4, and i wasn't able to find a method called `src`, in the line above `$captcha->src($config)`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Important Note: Change the captcha_img('flat') to laavel4 syntax. The logic is same for both.

**Captcha HTML-**

```
<div class="form-group refereshrecapcha">
{!! captcha_img('flat') !!}
</div>
<input id="captcha" class="form-control" type="text" name="captcha" data-validation="required" >
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="refreshCaptcha()">Refresh</a>
```

Create a function inside a controller that regenerate the captcha code.

**Controller Code-**

```
public function refereshCapcha(){
    return captcha_img('flat');
}
```

**Validate Captcha Request-**

```
'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
```

Mark your function into the route file that can you call it using ajax.

**Route File-**

```
Route::get('/refereshcapcha', 'HelperController@refereshCapcha');
```

Create a function for make a ajax request

**AJAX-**

```
<script>
function refreshCaptcha(){
$.ajax({
url: "/refereshcapcha",
type: 'get',
  dataType: 'html',        
  success: function(json) {
    $('.refereshrecapcha').html(json);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert('Try Again.');
  }
});
}
</script>
```